# Предварительно скомпилированные заголовки VS2010

Tags: pch, c++

Не могу найти где собака зарылась, при компиляции выдаёт ошибку:

```
 fatal error C1083: Cannot open precompiled header file: 'Debug\QUIK_TRADER.pch': No such file or directory
```

В свойствах проекта всё включено (Precompiled Header: Use(/Yu)), includ`ы прописаны, а он (компилятор) одно и тоже пишет! Куда копать, кого искать!?

Comment: Возникает вопрос, в каких случаях использовать Precompiled Header ключ Use а в каких Create в настройках проекта?

Comment: Попробуйте принудительно перестроить проект

Comment: Раньше никогда не пользовался, сейчас решил разобраться, если проект создавать с нуля, добавлять все файлы вручную (stdafx.h), свойствах проекта выбрать Precompiled Header: Use(/Yu), то оказывается файл ".pch" сам не создаётся, из за этого и ошибка, а если указать Precompiled Header: Create,  то создаётся файл ".pch"! Получается, что если я добавляю в stdafx.h новые заголовочные файлы, то необходимо в свойствах проекта выбирать Create, а затем Use!?

Comment: Обновляется он сам при добавлении инклудов. Если выбирать при создании проект уже с Precompiled Header, то и создастся он сам. А сломаться все может если потерять или переименовать файлы.

Comment: а stdafx.h везде ли первым инклюдом идёт?

Comment: stdafx.h - идёт первым, получается один раз PCH нужно создать вручную (если он не был создан), а дальше всё будет обновляться автоматически?

Comment: Раздельная компиляция - зло.

Comment: @Flammable Почему-это? ;) Скорее уж pch-зло

Comment: @Flammable 
А какая альтернатива, для средних-крупных проектов?

Comment: @manking, а это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: @Flammable не сталкиваюсь с такими проблемами =(((

Comment: >> не сталкиваюсь с такими проблемами =(((

Это, скорее, потому, что вы не пишете на c++. Иначе как еще можно было не столкнуться с копипастом сигнатур функций из cpp в hpp и обратно со всеми вытекающими.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Иногда само решение глючится(часто при удалении каких либо файлов из папок решения) и приходится создавать новый проект.

При создании нового проекта надо указывать опцию "Использовать прекомпилированный заголовок."
В настройках(свойствах) проекта необходимо указывать ключ (/Yu - Использовать) во вкладке 
свойства конфигурации - C/С++ -  предварительно откомпилированные заголовки. 
Сам файл .pch будет создан автоматически.

Для того чтобы прекомпилированный заголовок правильно функционировал необходимо чтобы 
в "обозревателе решений" `во вкладке "Заголовочные файлы".  находился stdafx.h, а во вкладке "Файлы исходного кода" stdafx.cpp.`
Система сама автоматически их там создаёт.

В файле stdafx.cpp
должно быть включение файла #include "stdafx.h"